# Selecting out a value with Special Characters and Insert into another table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, special-characters

I am facing some issue here and hope to get technical advise from you guys.
I have the below data with special characters from `TableA`:

```
ID       Data
-----   -------
101     ABÇ.123
```

Here is `TableA` column datatype:

```
Name  Type
----  --------------
ID    NUMBER
Data  VARCHAR2(2000)
```

I select this Data out by using the query below:

```
SELECT Data
INTO   var_x
FROM   TableA
WHERE  ID = 101;
```

After that I perform an `INSERT` statement to `TableB` using the query below:

```
INSERT INTO TableB
( 
  DataB 
)
VALUES
(
  var_x
);
```

Here is `TableB` column `datatype` and `var_x` datatype:

```
Name   Type
----   --------------
DataB  VARCHAR2(2000)

var_x  VARCHAR2(500)
```

However, I received the below error message after I test on the scripts:

> PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

Is it there is other way to select a data with special characters and insert it to another table? Please advice.

Thanks!

Comment: Please include the exact data type definitions for the tables involved. And also post your complete PL/SQL code that performs both the query and the insert, make sure you include the variable definitions, like `var_x`.

Comment: What is the declaration of `TableA`, `TableB`, and `var_x`?  If you are getting an error inserting data into `TableB`, that implies that the `DataB` column is too small.  My guess is that you're using a database with a variable length character set (AL32UTF8), that you have defined `TableB.DataB` to be, say, 7 bytes in length, and are getting tripped up by the fact that your actual data is 7 characters long but requires 8 bytes of storage.  You likely want to define `TableB.DataB` as being 7 characters rather than 7 bytes in length.

Comment: @JustinCave I have added the table and variable declaration. Thanks!

Comment: At what point do you get the error?  Why is `var_x` declared as a `varchar2(500)` rather than a 2000 like the source and destination table?  Are both tables defined using character length semantics?  Byte length semantics?  Your edits don't include that.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that `var_x` is declared to be big enough to handle the data that can be inserted in `DataB`.

So change it to `varchar2(2000)`.

Another way you can declare your `var_x` to avoid having to make sure you are declaring it of the right size is by declaring it like this:

```
var_x TableB.DataB%type; -- declares var_x to be of the same type as the DataB column
```

**EDIT:**

It goes without saying that you should also make sure that `var_x` is declared of enough size to also handle values in `TableA.Data`.  You didn't show the definition for that one. But I think you get the point.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what sstan mentioned, you can also do the select and insert in a single operation.

```
INSERT INTO TableB
( 
  DataB 
)
SELECT Data
FROM   TableA
WHERE  ID = 101;
```

This will tell you if the destination table's column is smaller than the source (which is not the case in your example).